# htlatex interrupted at '\:temp{rm}'

Tags: errors, debugging, htlatex

Using TL2013, I cannot compile documents with htlatex anymore.

For example, using:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}
test

\end{document}
```

I get:

```
$ htlatex test.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
... output ...
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/scrbook.4ht
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \MessageBreak 
l.201 \:temp{rm}
```

Is that a known bug? Am I missing something (it used to work fine with TL2012)?

Comment: See http://tug.org/pipermail/tex4ht/2014q1/000913.html

Comment: Thanks Ulricke. So I need to patch my local `tex4ht` copy, or is there a way to make this work without patching TL?

Comment: No idea, I didn't try. @michal.h21 will know it.

Comment: Right, or @cv-radhakrishnan probably.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

** another edit **

I've found that link to `tex4ht-4ht.tex` file was pointing to quite old revision, so provided patch may fail on this file. Please download [this version](http://svn.gnu.org.ua/viewvc/tex4ht/trunk/lit/tex4ht-4ht.tex?view=markup)

**edit:**

original patch was already applied to `tex4ht` sources in the source repository. as Ulrike pointed out, `scrartcl` still doesn't work. so I made new version:

```
--- tex4ht-4ht.tex  (revision 129)
+++ tex4ht-4ht.tex  (working copy)
@@ -17032,6 +17032,7 @@
 % scrartcl.4ht (|version), generated from |jobname.tex
 % Copyright |CopyYear.1999. Eitan M. Gurari
 |<TeX4ht copywrite|>
+|<scr old fonts|>
 \input article.4ht
 |<scr artcl, reprt, book|>
 \Hinput{scrartcl}
@@ -17218,24 +17219,7 @@
 \ifx \@openbib@code\:UnDef \else
  \pend:def\@openbib@code{\labelsep\z@}
 \fi
-\def\:temp#1#2!*?: {\def\:temp{#1}}
-\expandafter\:temp\usepackage!*?: 
-\def\:tempa{\@latex@e@error}
-\ifx \:temp\:tempa \else
-   \def\popthree#1#2#3#4{#4}
-   \def\:tempa#1#2#3#4{\tmp:toks{#1{#2}}%
-   \long\expandafter\edef\csname #4 \endcsname{\the\tmp:toks
-        {\expandafter\noexpand
-    \csname o:\expandafter\expandafter\:gobble\expandafter\string \popthree#3:\endcsname}}} 
-\def\:temp#1{%
-  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\:tempa\csname #1 \endcsname{#1}}
-\:temp{rm}
-\:temp{sf}
-\:temp{tt}
-\:temp{bf}
-\:temp{it}
-
-\fi
+|<scr old fonts|>
   \let\:tempc\listoffigures
 \pend:def\:tempc{\begingroup \a:listoffigures
    \def\@starttoc{\:tableofcontents[lof]\:gobble}}
@@ -17434,24 +17418,7 @@
 \ifx \@openbib@code\:UnDef \else
  \pend:def\@openbib@code{\labelsep\z@}
 \fi
-\def\:temp#1#2!*?: {\def\:temp{#1}}
-\expandafter\:temp\usepackage!*?: 
-\def\:tempa{\@latex@e@error}
-\ifx \:temp\:tempa \else
-   \def\popthree#1#2#3#4{#4}
-   \def\:tempa#1#2#3#4{\tmp:toks{#1{#2}}%
-   \long\expandafter\edef\csname #4 \endcsname{\the\tmp:toks
-        {\expandafter\noexpand
-  \csname o:\expandafter\expandafter\:gobble\expandafter\string \popthree#3:\endcsname}}}
-\def\:temp#1{%
-  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\:tempa\csname #1 \endcsname{#1}}
-\:temp{rm}
-\:temp{sf}
-\:temp{tt}
-\:temp{bf}
-\:temp{it}
-
-\fi
+|<scr old fonts|>
   \let\:tempc\listoffigures
 \pend:def\:tempc{\begingroup \a:listoffigures
    \def\@starttoc{\:tableofcontents[lof]\:gobble}}
@@ -17607,7 +17574,26 @@
 }
 >>>

+\<scr old fonts\><<<
+\def\:temp#1#2!*?: {\def\:temp{#1}}
+\expandafter\:temp\usepackage!*?: 
+\def\:tempa{\@latex@e@error}
+\ifx \:temp\:tempa \else
+   \def\popthree#1#2#3#4{#4}
+   \def\:tempa#1#2#3#4{\tmp:toks{#1{#2}}%
+   \long\expandafter\edef\csname #4 \endcsname{\the\tmp:toks
+        {\expandafter\noexpand
+  \csname o:\expandafter\expandafter\:gobble\expandafter\string \popthree#3:\endcsname}}}
+\def\:temp#1{%
+  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\:tempa\csname #1 \endcsname{#1}}
+\:temp{rm}
+\:temp{sf}
+\:temp{tt}
+\:temp{bf}
+\:temp{it}

+\fi
+>>>

 \<addchap confic\><<<
 \ifx \@@maybeautodot\:UnDef
```

apply patch with

```
patch tex4ht-4ht.tex < koma-new.patch
tex tex4ht-4ht.tex
```

and copy generated `scr*.4ht` files to the directory with your document.

I will send this patch to `tex4ht` mailing list tomorrow so the sources will be updated soon, I hope, and this new patch will be no longer needed

---

**old version:**

Yes, it is known bug, it was caused by new Koma Script version in TL 2013. You can read some more information [here](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex4ht/2014q1/000913.html). I created patch for tex4ht [literary sources](http://svn.gnu.org.ua/viewvc/tex4ht/trunk/lit/tex4ht-4ht.tex?revision=111&view=markup), `scrfonts.patch`:

```
--- /home/mint/Downloads/tex4ht-4ht(1).tex  2014-01-20 10:10:43.922759293 +0100
+++ tmp/tex4ht-4ht.tex  2014-01-20 10:15:29.566168889 +0100
@@ -17243,10 +17243,11 @@
 \expandafter\:temp\usepackage!*?: 
 \def\:tempa{\@latex@e@error}
 \ifx \:temp\:tempa \else
+   \def\popthree#1#2#3#4{#4}
    \def\:tempa#1#2#3#4{\tmp:toks{#1{#2}}%
    \long\expandafter\edef\csname #4 \endcsname{\the\tmp:toks
         {\expandafter\noexpand
-   \csname o:\expandafter\:gobble\string #3:\endcsname}}}
+    \csname o:\expandafter\expandafter\:gobble\expandafter\string \popthree#3:\endcsname}}} 
 \def\:temp#1{%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\:tempa\csname #1 \endcsname{#1}}
 \:temp{rm}
@@ -17458,10 +17459,11 @@
 \expandafter\:temp\usepackage!*?: 
 \def\:tempa{\@latex@e@error}
 \ifx \:temp\:tempa \else
+   \def\popthree#1#2#3#4{#4}
    \def\:tempa#1#2#3#4{\tmp:toks{#1{#2}}%
    \long\expandafter\edef\csname #4 \endcsname{\the\tmp:toks
         {\expandafter\noexpand
-   \csname o:\expandafter\:gobble\string #3:\endcsname}}}
+  \csname o:\expandafter\expandafter\:gobble\expandafter\string \popthree#3:\endcsname}}}
 \def\:temp#1{%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\:tempa\csname #1 \endcsname{#1}}
 \:temp{rm}
```

you need to download the file `tex4ht-4ht.tex`, move it to some temporary dir and run:

```
patch tex4ht-4ht.tex
tex tex4ht-4ht.tex
```

this will generate bunch of `.4ht` files, `scrbook.4ht`, `scratcl.4ht` and `scrreport.4ht` among them. as I hope this patch will find its way to `tex4ht` sources, place needed files to the directory with your document, not to the local texmf tree

Comment: The patch seems to work for scrbook and scrreprt but not for scrartcl. There I still get the error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you are right, `scrartcl` uses definitions for standard article class, not defintions used by `scrbook` and `scrreprt` with `tex4ht`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer do you have installed svn repo of `tex4ht`? does it contain patched version for `scrbook`? it should according to logs, but it seems that patch haven't been applied

Comment: No I simply downloaded the tex and applied the patch. Apart from this I only have the normal texlive files.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added new patch, it should work for `scrartcl` now

Comment: Thanks for the new patch. I will try to test it. Is there a chance that the changes find their way to CTAN and into the TeXsystems?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Karl updates TeXlive directly. I don't know why CTAN isn't updated, maybe it would require to adapt build system?

Comment: Sorry due to the problem with scrartcl I didn't realize that in texlive tex4ht is actually up-to-date. But miktex not ;-(.

Comment: @michal.h21 Patch fails: `patch tex4ht-4ht.tex < koma-new.patch
patching file tex4ht-4ht.tex
Hunk #2 FAILED at 17219.
patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
Hunk #4 succeeded at 17591 with fuzz 1.
1 out of 4 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file tex4ht-4ht.tex.rej`
I used tex4ht-4ht.tex in rev129 from http://svn.gnu.org.ua/viewvc/tex4ht/trunk/lit/tex4ht-4ht.tex?view=log

Comment: @KeksDose this is strange, I created new patch again, it should be fine hopefully

Comment: @michal.h21 Maybe I make a mistake, but again patching fails: `patch tex4ht-4ht.tex < koma-new.patch
patching file tex4ht-4ht.tex
Hunk #2 FAILED at 17219.
patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
Hunk #4 succeeded at 17591 with fuzz 1.
1 out of 4 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file tex4ht-4ht.tex.rej`. But don't give to much to my opinion, if your test with a freshly downloaded tex4ht-4ht.tex work...

Comment: I am working on svn repository, which isn't something I am comfortable with, but I reverted all changes in working dir, so I think all files should be the same as when you download them.

Comment: @KeksDose I've found that link to `tex4ht-4ht.tex` is pointing to specific revision, which ius quite old, so this may be the reason why it fails. I will update my answer

Comment: @michal.h21 No, I'm sure I downloaded rev129.