# Why does htlatex not work as expected?

Tags: errors, conversion, tex4ht, html, htlatex

I am trying to use htlatex to get an HTML version of my thesis. pdflatex just works when I compile the .tex files with TexStudio. So I ran the following command from the command line:

```
htlatex main.tex
```

where `main.tex` is the entry point of my thesis. From there, several other files are included (which may include further .tex files). The output of htlatex is then:

```
C:\Users\Bastian\Desktop\github-master\Thesis>latex  \makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter
HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle
\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}
makeatother\HCode .a.b.c.\input  main
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
(C:\Users\Bastian\Desktop\github-master\Thesis\main.tex
(C:\devel\latex\tuddesign\tex\latex\tuddesign\tudthesis.cls
Document Class: tudthesis 2009/05/15 0.96 Joe Werner's TUD-Design-Manual packag
e
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\keyval.tex")))
(C:\devel\latex\tuddesign\tex\latex\tuddesign\tudreport.cls
Document Class: tudreport 2009/11/17 1.13 Clemens von Loewenich's and Joe Werne
r's TUD-Design package
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty")
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrreprt.cls
Document Class: scrreprt 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script document class (report)

(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrkbase.sty
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrbase.sty
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrlfile.sty
Package scrlfile, 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

)))
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\tocbasic.sty
)

Class scrreprt Warning: You've used obsolete option `bibtotoc'.
(scrreprt)              Usage of this option indicates an old document and
(scrreprt)              is deprecated.
(scrreprt)              You should simply replace
(scrreprt)              usage of option `bibtotoc' by `bibliography=totoc'.


Class scrreprt Warning: You've used obsolete option `liststotoc'.
(scrreprt)              Usage of this option indicates an old document and
(scrreprt)              is deprecated.
(scrreprt)              You should simply replace
(scrreprt)              usage of option `liststotoc' by `listof=totoc'.


(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrsize11pt.
clo)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\typearea.sty
Package typearea, 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

)) (C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\usepackage.4ht)
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\calc.sty")
(C:\devel\latex\tuddesign\tex\latex\tuddesign\colours\tudcolours.sty
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\dvips.def"))
(C:\devel\latex\tuddesign\tex\latex\tuddesign\colours\tudcolours.cfg)
(C:\devel\latex\tuddesign\tex\latex\tuddesign\colours\tudcolours.def))
(C:\devel\latex\tuddesign\tex\latex\tuddesign\report\tudreprt_fonts.sty
(C:\devel\latex\tuddesign\tex\latex\tuddesign\base\tudfonts.sty
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\textcomp.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.def"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fix-cm.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.def"))
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\mathdesign\mathdesign.st
y
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\mathdesign\mdbch\mdbch.c
fg)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\mathdesign\mdbch\mdbch.s
ty (C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\mathdesign\mdfont.def
)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\mathdesign\mdsffont.def)
 (C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\mathdesign\mdttfont.def
)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\mathdesign\mdbch\t1mdbch
.fd)) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def")))))
(C:\devel\latex\tuddesign\tex\latex\tuddesign\base\tudpage.sty
(C:\devel\latex\tuddesign\tex\latex\tuddesign\base\tudpaper.sty
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg")))
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\eso-pic\eso-pic.sty
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\atbegshi.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")))
(C:\devel\latex\tuddesign\tex\latex\tuddesign\base\tudrules.sty)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg")))

Class scrreprt Warning: Usage of package `fancyhdr' together
(scrreprt)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
(scrreprt)              I'd suggest to use
(scrreprt)              package `scrpage2' or `scrlayer-scrpage'.
(scrreprt)              Nevertheless, using requested
(scrreprt)              package `fancyhdr' on input line 47.

(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty))
(C:\devel\latex\tuddesign\tex\latex\tuddesign\base\tudheading.sty

Class scrreprt Warning: Usage of package `titlesec' together
(scrreprt)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
(scrreprt)              I'd suggest to use the package only
(scrreprt)              if you really need it, because it breaks several
(scrreprt)              KOMA-Script features, i.e., option `headings' and
(scrreprt)              the extended optional argument of the section
(scrreprt)              commands .
(scrreprt)              Nevertheless, using requested
(scrreprt)              package `titlesec' on input line 12.

(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\titlesec\titlesec.sty)
(C:\devel\latex\tuddesign\tex\latex\tuddesign\base\tudheading.def)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\titlesec\block.tss)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\titlesec\titletoc.sty))
(C:\devel\latex\tuddesign\tex\latex\tuddesign\base\tudredef.sty)
(C:\devel\latex\tuddesign\tex\latex\tuddesign\report\tudreprt_title.sty))
(C:\devel\latex\tuddesign\tex\latex\tuddesign\thesis\tudthess_title.sty))
(C:\Users\Bastian\Desktop\github-master\Thesis\config/package-import.tex
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\latin1.def"))
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\german\german.sty
v2.5e 1998-07-08)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrtime.sty)
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty"

Package auxhook Warning: Cannot patch \document,
(auxhook)                using \AtBeginDocument instead.

) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty)

Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.

)

Package hyperref Message: Driver: htex4ht.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\htex4ht.def")
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\enumitem\enumitem.sty)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\listings\listings.sty
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\listings\lstmisc.sty)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\listings\listings.cfg))
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\soul\soul.sty)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\multirow\multirow.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ltxmisc\varwidth.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\tabularx.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\array.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"))
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\semantic\semantic.sty
Semantic Package v2.0(epsilon) [2003/10/28]
CVSId: $Id: semantic.dtx,v 1.11 2003/10/28 13:45:57 turtle Exp $
Loading features:
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\semantic\ligature.sty)
 math mode ligatures,
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\semantic\infernce.sty)
 inference rules,
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\semantic\tdiagram.sty)
 T diagrams,
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\semantic\reserved.sty)
 reserved words,
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\semantic\shrthand.sty)
 short hands,
and general definitions.

)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\adjustbox.sty
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\adjcalc.sty)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\trimclip.sty
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\collectbox\collectbox.st
y)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\tc-dvips.def))
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\ifoddpage\ifoddpage.sty)
)) (C:\Users\Bastian\Desktop\github-master\Thesis\config/macros.tex)
(C:\Users\Bastian\Desktop\github-master\Thesis\config/code-formatting.tex)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.4ht
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 TeX4ht info is available in the log file
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
) (C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty
--- needs --- tex4ht main ---
(C:\Users\Bastian\Desktop\github-master\Thesis\main.tmp)
(C:\Users\Bastian\Desktop\github-master\Thesis\main.xref)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht)
 (C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\latex.4ht
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht)
) (C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\fontmath.4ht
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht)
) (C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\ifthen.4ht
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht)
) (C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\scrreprt.4ht
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \MessageBreak
l.272 \:temp{rm}

?
```

What am I supposed to do now? The working directory does not contain any .html file afterwards. However, the output in the terminal does not show any message which I would identify as an error message.

Comment: Well `! Missing \endcsname` is a quite clear error message. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161229/htlatex-interrupted-at-temprm/161239#161239

Comment: this bug should be fixed now in the current texlive - https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?205

Comment: Ah ok. So the error message that Ulrike mentioned is actually a bug?

Comment: @Bastian that was caused by bug in tex4ht support for koma script. either try if updating texlive help, or use patch from the answer Ulrike had linked to

Comment: @michal.h21: As far as I know newer tex4ht-files are not on CTAN, and so miktex doesn't see bug corrections (how do texlive get them, from Karl?). Would it be possible either to upload newer versions or at least to put somewhere a tds.zip which could be installed (rather) easily by miktex users?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Whatever, anything is better than starting to patch tex4ht at the user level, for every single installation. Thank you for checking that there has not been an update to tex4ht.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't have TL 2014 so I can't confirm, but I posted some patches few weeks ago and Karl replied that he updated TL. I don't know why CTAN was not updated (no update since Eitan's death, it seems)

Comment: @michal.h21: I don't want to add more burden on Karl, but patches are not really useful for a normal user (I e.g. had some trouble to get the gnu patch working on windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad news: The message is the result of a bug.

**EDIT**: As Ulrike writes today (Juli 31, 2014), the bug in tex4ht has not been removed yet.

Good news: You simply could tell tex4ht to go on. Just type "R" (or was it Ctrl-R?), and the compilation will go on.

Comment: Ok, with "R" it goes on. Unfortunately the inclusion of other files is not done properly: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194246/htlatex-will-not-include-files-properly